# Train test dataset in Data Pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, I am building a data pipeline, in which I built two iterators for train, test set from tfrecord. The training works fine, but the problem occurs when inputting test set to graph.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     X_video_train,X_audio_train,y = dataset('frame_sample/train.tfrecord')
     X_video_test,X_audio_test,y = dataset('frame_sample/test.tfrecord')

     #Input:Train Set
     logits_train = graph(X_video_train,X_audio_train,training=True)
     train = training(logits_train)
```

This code just fine, after this when I call `sess.run` and `train` it. It trains the model, and by using logits of logits_train, I get train accuracy.

But to get test accuracy when I call

```
logits_test,y = graph(X_video_test,X_audio_test,training=False)
acc,predict_proba = evaluation(logits_test,y)
```

It give me error

> ValueError: Variable bidirectional_rnn/fw/fwd_lstm_1/kernel already
>   exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or
>   reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? :

Then i passed a train test parameter in graph, which creates a new variable for train and test. But I think that creating a whole new graph for test set.

I am thinking of using Varscope Reuse, but does it also create new graph?, instead of getting logits from trained graph?

I just dont understand how I input test data to graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is thrown because you are re defining the graph in your test function.
The fact that you are training or testing a model should not be related to the graph. The graph should be defined once with a placeholder as input. Then you can populate this placeholder with either train or test data.

Some operations like batch normalization change their behaviour when testing. If your model contains these OPs you should pass a boolean to your feed dictionary like so:

```
# Model definition
...
h = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h, training=is_training_pl)
... 

# Training
_, l = sess.run([train_op, loss], {x_pl: x_train_batch,
                                   y_pl: y_train_batch, 
                                   is_training_pl: True})
...
# Testing
l = sess.run(loss, {x_pl: x_test_batch,
                    is_training_pl: False})
```

In the case you are using the new tf.data.Dataset API, here is an adapted code snippet using a feedable iterator:

```
# Define training and validation datasets with the same structure.
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset ...
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset ...

# A feedable iterator is defined by a handle placeholder and its structure. We
# could use the `output_types` and `output_shapes` properties of either
# `training_dataset` or `validation_dataset` here, because they have
# identical structure.
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
    handle, training_dataset.output_types, training_dataset.output_shapes)

next_element = iterator.get_next() # THIS WILL BE USED AS OUR INPUT

# You can use feedable iterators with a variety of different kinds of iterator
# (such as one-shot and initializable iterators).
training_iterator = training_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
validation_iterator = validation_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

# The `Iterator.string_handle()` method returns a tensor that can be evaluated
# and used to feed the `handle` placeholder.
training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
validation_handle = sess.run(validation_iterator.string_handle())

...
# Model definition
input = next_element
...
h = tf.layers.batch_normalization(h, training=is_training_pl)
... 


# Training
_, l = sess.run([train_op, loss], {is_training_pl: True,
                                   handle: training_handle})

# Validation
sess.run(validation_iterator.initializer)
l = sess.run(loss, {is_training_pl: False,
                    handle: validation_handle})
```

Comment: I think I am not clear enough. The data is coming from one_shot_iterator.  I might be wrong, but I think data is coming as the tensor, not numpy array.  So what is the use of using feed_dict here and placeholders when you can pass data directly to graph?

Comment: Edited my answer